# Style tag in json response breaks in ie?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON response with the style tag in it. When i validate with jsonlint, it shows invalid JSon. Please anyone help me whats wrong in this. when i try to execute the code firefox gives the correct output. But only IE is causing the issue.

For example:

```
{   
"contentHTML": "<style type=\"text/css\">\nbody\n{\n  margin:0;
    \n  \n}\n\n.centerComponents\n{\n  margin:auto;
    \n  text-align:left;
    \n}\n\n#element1\n{\n  width:984px;
    \n}\n\n#c1315402137156\n{\n  width:984px;
    \n  min-height:98px;
    \n  height:auto !important;
    \n  height:98px;
    \n  display:inline;
    \n  float:left;
    \n}\n\n#c1315402137155\n{\n  width:984px;
    \n  min-height:150px;
    \n  height:auto !important;
    \n  height:150px;
    \n  margin:2px 0 0 0;
    \n  display:inline;
    \n  float:left;
    \n}\n\n#element2\n{\n  width:984px;
    \n  display:inline;
    \n  float:left;
    \n}\n\n#element3\n{\n  width:243px;
    \n  display:inline;
    \n  float:left;
    \n}\n\n#c1315402137154\n{\n  width:243px;
    \n  min-height:547px;
    \n  height:auto !important;
    \n  height:547px;
    \n  margin:20px 0 0 0;
    \n  display:inline;
    \n  float:left;
    \n}\n\n#c1315402137157\n{\n  width:100px;
    \n  min-height:100px;
    \n  height:auto !important;
    \n  height:100px;
    \n  margin:27px 138px 0 5px;
    \n  display:inline;
    \n  float:left;
    \n}\n\n#element4\n{\n  width:740px;
    \n  margin:0 0 0 1px;
    \n  display:inline;
    \n  float:left;
    \n}\n\n#c1315402137257\n{\n  width:740px;
    \n  min-height:5px;
    \n  height:auto !important;
    \n  height:5px;
    \n  margin:30px 0 0 0;
    \n  display:inline;
    \n  float:left;
    \n}\n\n#c1315402137158\n{\n  width:740px;
    \n  min-height:423px;
    \n  height:auto !important;
    \n  height:423px;
    \n  margin:1px 0 0 0;
    \n  display:inline;
    \n  float:left;
    \n}\n\n#c1315402137159\n{\n  width:740px;
    \n  min-height:994px;
    \n  height:auto !important;
    \n  height:994px;
    \n  display:inline;
    \n  float:left;
    \n}\n\n<\/style>"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you have new lines (actual line breaks, not the `\n` sequence) within your JSON, and this being JavaScript, that's not allowed.

Invalid:

```
var a = "Hello
          World";
```

Valid:

```
 var a = "Hello World";
```

Comment: This is correct; but it's "this being JSON, that's not allowed" (even though it's also true for JavaScript). It doesn't even have to be passed to JS before it's disallowed. Firefox is really "forgiving" for errors I've found, which can be more of a pain than a help.